# Coldfusion - Creating Custom Fields for my application

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, open-source, custom-fields

Im currently trying to develop a crm type app which allows my users to create custom fields. The application is being written in Coldfusion and MSSQL 2005, but realistically it shouldnt matter which languages are used.

What I would like to know, is there a particular methodology someone should follow when allowing users to create custom fields within their application ? or is there a framework out there on the internet that enables developers quick and easy access to creating an app that allows for custom fields.

More importantly, if there is anything that assists with this sort of functionality for Coldfusion that would be exceptional, or alternatively somesort of open source project that can be reviewed for their process.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089883/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-store-custom-fields-in-a-sql-database

Answer (score 1):

So am I in right in thinking you need a web form that allows the user to add columns to a SQL Server table?

In that case you would make a self-posting page, and if a certain parameter exists (.e.g hidden field with new custom field name), then you get ColdFusion to execute a stored procedure that accepts the new column name and runs an SQL ALTER TABLE statement to add that column to the table.